# What's the best POCO status tracking strategy? (EF)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco, wcf-ria-services

So I was reading about Entity Framework and based on my agile development scenario I decided to go with POCO objects.

But now I'm having some extra problems I don't know how to get away with.

I'm working with RIA services and Silverlight so when I'm going to Save an object of the server side I have to attach the object to an `ObjectContext`. The thing is that I must then change the `ObjectState` to Added or Modified.

So my question is what's the best approach to really know what state to change it to. I saw in [Julia Lerman](http://www.learnentityframework.com/)'s book that she uses a `State` attribute in her POCO  objects and she takes care managing that state on the client side before sending the object to the server. That state then is used to change the real EntitySate once attached.

I've also seen other samples where the Insert implementation checks on the Key of the Entity (object) to know whether it is new or not. For example, if `ProjectId` in my Project entity is 0 (zero) I know it has to be a new object.

To be honest I don't like any of those approaches because in both cases my developers have to do some extra-work to actually save the object.

I'd like the know pros and cons of both solutions and hopefully a new (better) solution I'm still not seing.

Comment: have you looked at self-tracking entities?

Comment: yes, but I need to use POCO :(

Answer (score 0):

You can still have self tracking entities and poco.  In visual studio if you search the community templates there is a self tracking poco template.  this is what you want to use.  If you can find the template look for your entities using Ientitywithobjecttracker.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456848.aspx

Comment: I know i can... but we're doing Agile development with unitesting and we desided to go with POCO, plain POCO

Comment: Self Tracking Entities are POCO.  They don't preclude any Unit Testing or Agile practices.  If you've produced a model that can't be changed then your only option is to manage change tracking yourself.  You've said that you don't want your devs having to write the tracking code so personally I'd go back and look at regenerating the model against the STE POCO template.  The other type of tracking is via EF proxies but as you're using RIA services you don't want to go down this route as the proxies don't play particularly nicely when serialised (according to Julie Lerman).